# Review implementation for Partial Ordering of Vectors

Tags: python

Partial ordering may be useful in some scientific contexts. This is quick prototype in Python, which I believe works correctly.

Do you notice any flaws? Can you provide a counter-example of wrong results? Additional test cases will be also rewarded with +1.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest as ut

def leq (L1, L2):
    assert len(L1) == len(L2)
    l = g = 0
    for v1, v2 in zip(L1, L2):
        if v1 < v2: 
            l += 1
        elif v1 > v2:
            g += 1
    return l >= 0 and g == 0

class Test (ut.TestCase):

    def test1 (self):
        V1 = [1, 2, 3]
        V2 = [1, 2, 2]
        self.assertFalse(leq(V1, V2))
        self.assertTrue(leq(V2, V1))

    def test2 (self):
        V1 = [1, 2, 3]
        V2 = [2, 2, 3]
        self.assertTrue(leq(V1, V2))
        self.assertFalse(leq(V2, V1))

    def test3 (self):
        V1 = [1, 2, 3]
        self.assertTrue(leq(V1, V1))

    def test4 (self):
        V1 = [1, 2, 3]
        V2 = [3, 2, 1]
        self.assertFalse(leq(V1, V2))
        self.assertFalse(leq(V2, V1))
```

**Edit:** redefining the `leq` function (thanks to Cary for the comment)

```
leq = lambda L1, L2: sum(v1 > v2 for v1, v2 in zip(L1, L2)) == 0
```

Proved to be working with the same unit test.

Same result, but using short-circuit logic and avoiding to scan both lists:

```
leq = lambda L1, L2: not any (v1 > v2 for v1, v2 in zip(L1, L2))
```

As suggested in comment, equivalent version, more natural:

```
leq = lambda L1, L2: all(v1 > v2 for v1, v2 in zip(L1, L2))
```

Comment: Decav, since `l >= 0` is always `true`, the `return` statement appears to be the same as `return g == 0`, suggesting that `false` is returned if and only if `v1 > v2` for at least one pair `v1, v2`.  In Ruby, this could be expressed `return !L1.zip.L2.any? {|v1,v2| v1 > v2}`.  (I'm not familiar with Python, so maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: Correct. Let me update the question

Comment: I wouldn't go for the solution with sum at it would iterate all the way instead of stopping as soon as possible. I am not a big fan of "not any" because it doesn't sound natural and I'd prefer :
leq = lambda L1, L2: all(v1 <= v2 for v1, v2 in zip(L1,L2))

Comment: @Josay, I added the `not any` indeed because of the short-circuit logic. The `all` is equivalent but actually more natural. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @Josey re `!any?` vs `all?`.  When I suggested the former I was just not thinking straight.  The two are obviously equivalent, as both terminate when they encounter `v1 > v2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much to say about it, good job!

- Documentation: explain the mathematical explanation of your partial ordering unless it's really that obvious for your intended readers
- Names:

  - In Python, names starting with uppercase letters are for class names: of course you're free to use your own convention, but this one makes it easy to share code between Python developers
  - Explicit is better than implicit: `less` is better than `l` which could also mean left or leave or whatever.
- Style: In Python (see PEP8), we usually don't but spaces before function definitions.
- Test cases: always add a test case for degenerate cases, eg. the empty list and lists of different lengths: those are the ones which usually fail.

(And +1 to the comments who should become an answer.)